# Unable to debug WCF RIA application after security update

Tags: c#, debugging, iis-7.5

After my system did its update last night I am unable to start the debugger for my Silverlight WCF RIA project.  I receive the following message:  "Unable to start debugging on the web server.  IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL".  If I swtich to the VS Development Server then I can debug the code.

Last night, the system wwas working just fine.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  Checking the update log a .Net security update is listed.

I am running VS 2010/Windows 7/IIS 7.5 - all up to date

Comment: I've found issues when debugging in W7 with VS2010. Are you running VS2010 as Administrator?

Comment: Yes.  That was it.  I have VS 2010 set to 'run as administrator' but Windows just launches it without the setting whenever it restarts from an update.

Comment: I've put it as an answer, can you accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you're running VS2010 as Administrator.